# Можно ли отключить уведомление про повторную отправку формы?

Tags: javascript

После перехода по форме на другую страницу, и нажатие F5 выводится модальное окно:

> На странице, которую вы ищете, использовалась введенная вами
>   информация. При возврате на эту страницу может потребоваться повторить
>   выполненные ранее действия. Продолжить?

Можно ли как то отключить это уведомление программно?

Comment: Нет отключить нельзя, после отправки данных с формы вам надо программно сделать новый page reload или редирект на другую страницу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно. Для этого требуется на странице-приёмнике (которая получает данные формы) выполнить редирект (redirect) на другую (или эту же) страницу.

При нажатии F5 браузер передаёт все данные, необходимые данной странице для отображения (в вашем случае - данные формы). И чтобы эти данные не передавались - нужно отправить браузер на страницу, не передавая при этом никаких данных формы.

Например, если вы добавляете на Stackoverflow новый вопрос - при отправке формы на сервер он добавляет новую запись в базу данных с переданными вами данными, после чего получает из базы ID только что созданного вопроса - и редиректит вас по URL вида: stackoverflow.com/question/{QUESTION_ID}, где QUESTION_ID - это идентификатор вашего вопроса в базе. В результате, после отправки вопроса и обновлении страницы, на которую вы попали, вы не отправляете ваш вопрос снова и снова с каждым обновлением (засоряя базу данных дублями вопроса), а просто обновляете страницу с результатом.